# Can I prevent selections from going to the end of the div?

Tags: html, css

I've got a div that has a large width but a small amount of text. When I select up to the end of the text, the selection goes off to the end of the div. Is there any way I can prevent that from happening?

Comment: Can you show us some code or maybe a screen shot?

Comment: Is the text inside set as a block element? that could be causing it's width to display all the way across

Comment: I'm not seeing this here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KVASD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `width:auto;` this will make your div wide equal to your text inside that `div`. But if you must have that `div` with large width try wrapping the text inside another `div` or `span` or `p` or anything you like and then giving it `width:auto;`.